# External JS to reload itself automatically?

Tags: javascript

I saw this code in this forum described to do that job as follows

```
<script id="myscript" src="src/to/file-with-your-custom-scripts.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#myscript').remove();
        $.getScript("src/to/file-with-your-custom-scripts.js", function() {
            $('script:last').attr('id', 'myscript');
        });
    }, 30000); // every 30 seconds

});
</script>
```

I run a radio station & my server gave me this code to show my songs played history but it only updates on a page refresh.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://server6.reliastream.com/theme      /widget_recenttracks.css" />
<span style="display:inline-block;padding:12px;width:340px;height:356px;border:4px solid #4E00E9;background:#0a0a0a;"><p style="font-size:18px; color:#1DBD01; font-weight:bold;">Last 5 plays on Boss 1</p><p style="font-size:20px; font-family:arial; color:#000000; font-weight:normal;">-</p>
<div id="cc_recent_tracks">Loading...</div>
<script id="myscript" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://server6.reliastream.com/system/recenttracks.js"></script>
<script id="myscript" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://server6.reliastream.com/js.php/boss1/recenttracks/rnd20"></script>
</span>
```

I couldn't get the code posted from here (up top) to work. Could anyone possibly assemble a proper construction where it would update the data about every minute?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the page every minute without using

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" >
```

or using js

```
setInterval(function() {
              window.location.reload();
            }, 100000);
```

or you can use ajax & update the content , without using page refresh